# How can I view the JMS message selector a client application is using against a WebSphereMQ Queue Manager

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

I would like to be able to view the exact JMS message selector SQL that a WebSphere MQ JMS client application is using on its receive call.

If I run the client application against TIBCO EMS as the JMS provider the TIBCO EMS Administration API provides visibility of this information.

When the client application is run against WebSphere MQ as the JMS provider I can use:

> display qstatus(MyQUEUE) type(handle) all

to see the consumers of the queue, but I can't see what JMS message selector the client has declared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently it's not possible to see the selector in use; other open options, message information can be seen via runqmsc or via Explorer. (In Explorer, the Applications Connection view can show you what is connected with associated information).

I would suggest that you raise a Request For Enhancement - the process is documented here http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21266802

Matthew